# how to resolve Spring Boot / Hibernate NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot / Hibernate app, using the following Maven POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>netgloo</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-mysql-jpa-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>spring-boot-mysql-jpa-hibernate</name>
  <description></description>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>netgloo.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

When I attempt to retrieve a record from Postgres, using Hibernate (5.2.1), I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.getFlushMode()Lorg/hibernate/FlushMode;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.prepareFlushMode(HibernateJpaDialect.java:183)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:169)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
```

What is the exact combination of libraries, which would allow me to pass this problem?

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 1.2.3 includes Hibernate 4.3.8. It's probably incompatible with Hibernate 5.

Either remove your explicit Hibernate dependencies (to use 4.3.8) or upgrade to Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE (latest) to get Hibernate 5 support.